# What's the reliability of Google Chart API service?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, reliability

I'm considering using Google Chart API. Is the API stable? Is the service uptime any good? There are no warranties about it on the [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/terms.html). Has anyone known of large downtime periods?

Comment: Probably would be a better question on webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just did that: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/whats-the-reliability-of-google-chart-api-service

Comment: @John This is off topic at webapps and belongs here as shown by the [google-charts] tag.

Comment: OK, it got closed over there.  Sorry for the wild goose chase, guys.

Comment: For what it's worth: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/740/are-api-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been only using it for a couple months, but I haven't had any downtime, or any degradation in chart generation speed.

I doubt Google would let this one go down for long... They use it themselves on Google Analytics.  For that fact alone, I feel comfortable using it.  Of course, if you want any guarantees, you will need a different solution.